# Question on definition of a density function for a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For a discrete random variable $X$ we have

$$f(x) = P(X = x) = k$$

where $0 \le k \le 1$. I.e the probability that $X$ takes on the value $x$ is some number between $0$ and $1$.

Now say I have continuous (and uniformly distributed) random variable with density function

$$f(x) = P(X = x) = \frac{1}{2}$$ when $1 < x < 3$ and $0$ elsewhere.

This is telling me that the probability $X$ takes on the value $x$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ beween $1$ and $3$.

But for a continuous random variable the probability it takes on any particular value is obviously $0$. So why does it say the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$ going by the definition of the density function?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement $f(x) = P(X = x)$ is wrong if $f(x)$ is a density.

In Physics, to find the mass of a small piece os something, you need to multiply its density by the volume of the small piece; there is a similar concept in trying to find a probability of an event from its probability density.

It might be easier to understand if you considered $P(x - \frac{\delta x} 2 \le X \lt x+\frac{\delta x} 2) \approx f(x) \delta x$ for a small interval of length $\delta x$ around $x$.  In this sense $f(x)$ is the derivative of a probability over an interval, and this can be formalised in a robust wasy.

In your example with $f(x) =\frac12$ for $1 \lt x \lt 3$, if you want the probability of $X$ being between $2.6$ and $2.9$, this would be $\frac12 (2.9-2.6)=0.15$. You might want to try other examples. If the density was not constant then you would want the integral $P(a \lt X \le b) = \int_a^b f(x)\; dx$.

Answer (score 0):

For an absolutely continuous random variable $X$, its density function $f_X$ is such that
$$P(X \leq a) = \int_{-\infty}^a f_X$$
So $\displaystyle P(X = a) = \int_a^a f_X = 0$.

It's not true that $f_X(a) = P(X=a)$; and $f_X$ may not even be a probability. You may have misunderstood it because while it's true that for an absolutely continuous r.v. $f_X$ is used to calculate the cumulative distribution function $F$ the same way $P$ is used for a discrete r.v., you still need to integrate $f_X$ to evaluate $P(X=a)$.

Comment: It is said that a random variable $ X $ is continuous if its distribution function $ F_X $ is continuous (on $\mathbb{R}$) or equivalently if $\mathbb{P}(X=x) =0$ for all $ x \in \mathbb{R}$. It is easy to verify that any random variable $X$ that admit density (i.e. the distribution of $X$ is absolutely continuous) $f_X $ is continuous.